# Android Database delete entry _ID Problems

Tags: android, sqlite, android-adapterview

I have a list view where my SQL query will be displayed.
Now I have added an `OnItemClickListener` to delete entrys on click:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1,int arg2, long arg3){
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);      
    final String Name = lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString();
    final String ID = String.valueOf(arg3);

    CharSequence dbeintrag = getString(R.string.dbeintrag);
    CharSequence yes = getString(R.string.yes);
    CharSequence no = getString(R.string.no);
    Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(EP.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle(Name);
    alertDialog.setMessage(dbeintrag);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            deleteentry(Name,ID);
            fillSQLData(); // refresh
        } }); 

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        } }); 
    alertDialog.show();
}
});  

}

 public void deleteentry(String Name,long ID) // Lösche Eintrag
    {
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null);
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        ID = ID+1; // Anpassen zur DB

        SQLiteDatabase database = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL("DELETE FROM Heute WHERE Name='"+Name+"' and _id='"+ID+"'");
        mPLAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Now I have the problem that my ID in the Database is not the ID I get from the `onItemClick` function.
For example, I'll add 3 entries, delete all, add 3 new ones. For the function the first entry is 0, in the SQL database its 4...

What is the best solution to fix this?

Than you very much!

Comment: Did you have a chance to try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override this method to your adapter class so you can retrieve the id in onItemClick.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return yourList.get(position);
}
```

In onItemClick

```
final String ID = String.valueOf(lv.getAdapter().getItemId(arg2)); 
//long id = ((YourAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getItemId(arg2);
```

Please see [Android OnItemClickListener long id parameter is not giving field id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972359/android-onitemclicklistener-long-id-parameter-is-not-giving-field-id) and [view.getId() returning wrong id in OnItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610464/view-getid-returning-wrong-id-in-onitemclicklistener)

Edit: so here's Oli's changes:

```
final long id = ((EPListAdapter)arg0.getAdapter()).getItemId(arg2);
```

> "Its important to use .notifyDataSetChanged(); on the Adapter. Else it wont work."

Comment: Ah now it worked! I used the wrong adapter ..

    final long id = ((EPListAdapter)arg0.getAdapter()).getItemId(arg2);

Comment: Its important to use .notifyDataSetChanged(); on the Adapter. Else it wont work.